# Out of memory error when decoding a Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when I try to decode an image from the Resources. The image I'm trying to decode isn't even a large image. It's a png with the size of 53KB and resolution of 500x500. 
Here's the code:

```
 imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(ctx.Resources, Resource.Drawable.nopic);
```

I want to use bitmap.compress but I want to return the bitmap and not the image file. I shouldn't be getting this error in the first place. What's the best way I can fix it?

Comment: Try to cache your bitmap and load it in your view     https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Which Android Version do you test this on? How often is the decode operation called?  When is the decode performed (from experience: Decoding bitmaps during configuration changes is quite troublesome)? Have you considered using a library that does asynchronous decoding and caching for you?

Comment: @dhke I haven't looked into caching yet. The decode operation probably in every second as I'm switching between different views. My app has a list of users with their profile images. If a user doesn't have a profile pic, the image from the resource is set by default as the profile pic. and that's the pic which crashes the app 1 in 4 times the decode operation is called